# Purpose of pose estimations in tod_detecting?

Tags: ros, tod-detecting, object-recognition, tod-training

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What is the purpose of the pose estimations in tod_detecting when recognizing textured objects using `"rosrun tod_detecting recognizer --mode=0 ..."`? Are they relevant for the recognition process (**not** running kinect mode)?

[image: image description]

(*picture showing the estimated pose of a training object, as described by rvec and tvec*)

Why do we need to make pose estimations in the tod_training pipeline, apart from using the pose estimation to segment the point cloud to generate a ROI mask? I mean the training pipeline does not really collect any real 3d features.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9537/purpose-of-pose-estimations-in-tod_detecting?/) by [Julius](https://answers.ros.org/users/252/julius/) on ROS Answers with karma: 960 on 2011-03-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't understand first part of your question.
We do pose estimation in training for calculation transformation between frames.

mode = xx

Now tod_detecting contains two recognizers. First version of TOD (textured_object_detection package) was implemented for recognizing objects on 5 MP prosilica dataset. Later Ethan and me began to refactor this code. In result we get two versions of detection algorithms: Kinect mode and TOD mode. Kinect mode gives better results on Kinect data, TOD mode gives better results on 5MP data.

---

Originally posted by [Alexander Shishkov](https://answers.ros.org/users/334/alexander-shishkov/) with karma: 191 on 2011-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Julius](https://answers.ros.org/users/252/julius/) on 2011-03-25**:
Thanks! I just wondered where the pose estimates are used in detecting objects. In other words,  is the pose estimation required in tod_detecting and if so, why? See http://answers.ros.org/question/537/are-my-findings-about-tod_detecting-correct